# Cloning the entire tr table entity in a given table row

Tags: jquery, html, performance, dom, html-table

I want to be able to clone a table tr with a textarea in it. each parent table row should have its own add and remove icons. So when I click the add icon, a new textarea is created, which th code does perfectly for the first row, but I have a problem removing. Another problem is that if I click the second add icon in row 2, it adds the textarea to row 1.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
<script src="<?php echo base_url().'Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js'?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url().'Scripts/migrate.js'?>" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                var addDiv = $('#addinput');
                var i = $('#addinput td').size() + 1;

                $('.addNew').on('click', function() {
                    $('<tr class="clone" id="row_'+i+'"><td ><textarea  id="p_new'+i+'" rows="1" cols="10" name="data[]" value="" placeholder="I am New" ></textarea><a href="#" class="remNew"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>img/remove.png" alt="x" width="15px" height="15px"></a><td> </tr>').appendTo(addDiv);
                    i++;

                    return false;
                });

                $('.remNew').on('click', function() {
                    if( i > 1 ) {
                       // row_id=$(this).attr('id');

                      $('#row_'+i).remove();
                        i--;
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            });

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>       

        <table border="1">
            <tr>

            <td id="addinput">
                <textarea  id="p_new" rows="1" cols="10" name="data[]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" ></textarea><a href="#" class="addNew"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>img/add.png" alt="+" width="15px" height="15px"></a>
            </td>
            </tr>
               <tr>           
            <td>
                <textarea  id="p_new_1" rows="1" cols="10" name="data[]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" ></textarea><a href="#" class="addNew"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>img/add.png" alt="+" width="15px" height="15px"></a>
            </td>
            </tr>

        </table>       

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why have you got elements with same IDs [addNew] in the first place? They are meant to be unique.

Comment: I have edited the id's but still no success

Comment: why are you appending a TR to the addDiv?Not sure if thats sematically correct. http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) use class for `addNew` instead of id.

2) You are appending new row to column (not sure why you want that)

Check here DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/CgwCC/

Adding and removing is working now.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 1;

    $('.addNew').on('click', function() {
        $('<tr class="clone"><td><textarea  id="p_new'+i+'" rows="1" cols="10" name="data[]" value="" placeholder="I am New" ></textarea><a href="#" class="remNew">-</a><td> </tr>').appendTo($(this).parent('td'));
        i++;

        return false;
    });

    $('.remNew').live('click', function() {
        var id = $(this).parentsUntil('tr.clone').attr('id');
        if( id != '1' ) {
          $(this).parentsUntil('tr.clone').remove();
          i--;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I am using jquery migrate.js to capture that

Comment: check my answer and demo again.

Comment: Thank you very much YEYENE, this has been a headache, cup of coffee on me. Thank you